# Proving Stirling numbers

Tags: discrete-mathematics, permutations, stirling-numbers

a) Prove $\sum_{k=0}^{n} s(n,k) = n!$, for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

So my idea was to start with induction over $n\\$.

- Base case: $n=1$

$\sum_{k=0}^{1}s(1,k)=s(1,0)+s(1,1) = 0+1=1 =1!$

- Inductive hypothesis. Assume true for $\sum_{k=0}^{n} s(n,k) = n!$
- Inductive step. Check the n+1 case. We get

$\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}s(n+1,k)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}s(n,k)+$

Could someone help me with the last step. I can not seem to understand how to split the last sum.

b) Prove $s(n,n-2) =\frac{1}{24}n(n-1)(n-2)(3n-1)$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N},n\geq2.$

I have tried proving b) by induction ( just like the problem below):
 (https://math.stackexchange.com/users/438651/thesmallprint), Proving $S(n,n-2) = \frac{n(n-1)(n-2)(3n-5)}{24}.$, URL (version: 2018-06-06): https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2810239

The problem is, that what I get in the Inductive step is: $s(n+1,n-1)=\frac{n(n-1)(3n^2+5n-10)}{24}$. Sadly I can not seem to factorize $3n^2+5n-10$. Some help with that would be appreciated.

Comment: @DietrichBurde \begin{align}
                S(n+1,n-1)&=S(n,n-2)+(n-1)S(n,n-1)\\
                &=\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)(3n-1)}{24}+(n-1){n\choose{2}}\\
                &=\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)(3n-1)}{24}+\frac{n(n-1)^2}{2}\\
                &=\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)(3n-1)+12n(n-1)^2}{24}\\
                &=\frac{n(n-1)((n-2)(3n-1)+12(n-1))}{24}\\
                &=\frac{n(n-1)(3n^2-n-6n+2+12n-12)}{24}\\
                &=\frac{n(n-1)(3n^2+5n-10)}{24}                                                                                           
                \end{align}

Comment: No, we get We get \begin{align}
                S(n+1,n-1)&=S(n,n-2)+(n-1)S(n,n-1)\\
                &=\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)(3n-5)}{24}+(n-1){n\choose{2}}\\
                &=\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)(3n-5)}{24}+\frac{n(n-1)^2}{2}\\
                &=\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)(3n-5)+12n(n-1)^2}{24}\\
                &=\frac{n(n-1)((n-2)(3n-5)+12(n-1))}{24}\\
                &=\frac{n(n-1)(3n^2+n-2)}{24}\\
                &=\frac{n(n-1)(3n-2)(n+1)}{24},
            \end{align}

Comment: @DietrichBurde So this means that the premise of the problem,$s_{n,n-2} = \frac{1}{24}n(n-1)(n-2)(3n-1)$, is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Recall that the Stirling numbers of the first kind satisfy the recurrence relation $s(n+1,k)=ns(n,k)+s(n-1,k)$. ($s(n,0)=0$)

The first part follow easily by induction.

For the second part,again induction and use
\begin{eqnarray*}
s(n,n-1)&=& \frac{n(n-1)}{2} \\
s(n+1,n-1)&=& n \, s(n,n-1)+ s(n,n-2).
\end{eqnarray*}